# Validation fires but doesn't show message on failure. What am I missing? MVC 5 Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't seem to get the Validation error messages to show under the input model fields on the View.

The [Required] tag above Description input makes the ModelState Invalid, but doesn't stop the submission. I have to catch it with checking the Model State. Am I missing some .js files? I dont' have any examples to doublecheck this.

Here is my model (notice I have only one [Required] for now):

```
public partial class Requests
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Lat { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Lng { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description of what you need is missing.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my View where the Description input needs input.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "20", @cols = "200" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller ActionResult (skinnied down)

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
 //THIS ALL WORKS IF Description HAS INPUT

}
else
{
  TempData["Saved"] = "Nothing saved yet. Look for reason.";
return RedirectToAction("StoreRequests", new { lat = requests.Lat, lng = requests.Lng });
}
```

On `ModelState` failure the user is directed to the correct View and `TempData` shows that nothing was saved. However, there is no error message on the View below the offending input, no `ValidationSummary` at the top of the view, and submission is not stopped on input mistake.

```
@if(TempData["Saved"] != null)
{
    <span style="color: red;">@TempData["Saved"].ToString()</span>
}
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I added these 2 and it worked. Probably had a couple more in the _Layout.cshtml. <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

If you want to make it an answer I will acept it.

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote. oh well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get client side validation (and therefore prevent the form being submitted if its invalid), you need to include the following scripts in you view (or layout).

```
jquery-{version}.js
jquery.validate.js
jquer.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

If you have the default bundles set up by VS when you create a new project, you can simply add the following to the view

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

In addition, you should not be redirecting if `ModelState` is invalid, but rather returning the current view, which will display any validation errors even if the user has disabled javascript. By redirecting, your lose current `ModelState` so no validation errors will be displayed in the view your redirecting to, not to mention that any data the user previously filled (except the 2 parameters your passing) will be lost.

```
public ActionResult Edit (Requests model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    // save you data and redirect
}
```

Comment: No. I never want to waste your time Stephen. You have solved so many things for me. Sorry I took so long. I just had other things that kept me away from the computer.

Comment: On ModelState Invalid I am returning to the previous View but I also am sending it an error message in TempData and sending it the same Lat/Lngs to populate the Google Maps again. Maybe there is a slicker way but I doubt my way will ever break in a million years.

Comment: @JustJohn, You should not be using `TempData` for that. Just add a `ModelState` error and return the view. `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Nothing saved yet. Look for reason."); return View(model);` and it will be displayed in the `@Html.ValidationSummary()`. But what is the point of that - when `ModelState` is invalid and you return the view, all the error messages are displayed in the `@Html.ValidationFor(m => m.yourProperty)` anyway. Under no circumstances should you be redirecting if `ModelState` is invalid.

Comment: Ok, looks like I have something to study this weekend. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following necessary `scripts` directly in your `.cshtml` file.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```